# Validation of a geometry in WKT format

Tags: java, geospatial, geotools, jts, wkt

I am new to GIS area and I need to validate a geometry in WKT format in java, to check whether a simple polygon is a closed loop, i.e the start and end points of the vertices should be the same. I am currently using jGeometry class of oracle spatial(com.oracle.sdoapi), get the first and last vertices and comparing them. also, i am using getType() method to check whether it is a simple polygon or not. The following is the piece of code that am using:

```
WKT wkt = new WKT();
JGeometry geometry = wkt.toJGeometry(wkt.getBytes());
double[] d1 = geometry.getFirstPoint();
double[] d2 = geometry.getLastPoint();
if(!jGeometry.getType() == jGeometry.GTYPE_POLYGON){
 //error message for other geometries
}
```

Is there any simple way of doing this or is there any API available? I dont want to reinvent the wheel, if it is already done and simple to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) contains a WKTReader class that will suit your purposes.   See http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/io/WKTReader.html.  You can use WKTReader to parse the WKT, and look for ParseExceptions, which indicate an invalid WKT.

If the WKT parses, you can then use the `instanceof` operator or `WKTReader.getGeometryType()` to determine the type of parsed Geometry class, and see if it's one of the Geometry types (Polygon or Multipolygon) with closed shells like Polygon or Multipolygon.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I tried to use this, but due to some licensing issues, I was later advised not to use JTS. I have used custom code to create a geodetic point class, convert the geometry into geodetic points and compared the first and last points.